# Matplotlib animation with lag in moving x axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a data file with 772 records, I read it in using Pandas and I plot the second column as a line. When the data is drawn the x axis seems to shift at a different rate to the points in the line?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(ylim=(-2047, 2047))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return line,
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", names=['status', 'heave', 'north', 'west'])

def animate(i):
        line.set_data(data.index, np.roll(data.heave,-i))
        ax.set_xlim(i-100,i+100)
        return line,
from matplotlib import animation

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=772, interval=10, blit=False)
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30)
```

Link to [data.csv](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb65b4d770e4a6c06e15#file-data-csv)

I'm running Windows 7, Python 2.7.5 both 64 bit and Matplotlib version 1.3.1